# render text with ground truth meta data

Tags: metadata, text-rendering

I'm Working On  Optical Character Recognition.In our work we need automatically generate some rendered word image and we need each characters location(boundary) in rendered word image. this meta data about rendered image is called ground truth.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a rendering c api called Pango wich has a function named pango_layout_Iter_get_char_extent() that can be used for that.

https://developer.gnome.org/pango/stable/pango-Layout-Objects.html#pango-layout-iter-get-char-extents